# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

Tags: java, arrays, classcastexception

I keep receiving a java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D error at productSales2025 = (double[]) projSales(); over here I'm trying to pull an answer from the method projSales and store it in the array productSales2025 (I may not be doing this right either, honestly idk), but I cant figure out why I'm getting this error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] productName = {"oComputer", "oTablet", "oCall", "oStream", "oClock"};
    int [] productPrice = {1825, 670, 880, 1910, 485};
    int [] productSales = {320, 174, 623, 59, 169};
    int productRevenue = 0;

    //loop to find the total product revenue for 2018
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        //multiplies product price by its corresponding product sale
        productRevenue = productPrice[i] * productSales[i]; //java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error (fixed)

        //increments the product revenue to get the total product revenue
        productRevenue += productRevenue;

    }
    //prints total product revenue
    System.out.println("Product Revenue for 2018 is $" + productRevenue);

    double[] productSales2025 = null;

    //loops to receive calculated estimates of the projected sales
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        //creates array for the projected sales of the year 2025
        productSales2025 = (double[]) projSales();//java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D
    }
    //prints product sales of the year 2025
        System.out.println("Product Sales for the year 2025 is: " + productSales2025);
} //closes main
//projected sales method
public static Object projSales() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the base sale?");
    int baseSales = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the growth rate?");
    double growthRate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the expected number of years?");
    int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();
    double projectedSales = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        //calculates the projected sales of the upcoming years
        projectedSales = (Math.pow(baseSales * (1 + (growthRate / 100)), numberOfYears));

    }

    input.close();

    return projectedSales;
} //closes projSales
```

Comment: What do you think should be result of `productSales2025 = (double[]) projSales()`? What should be content of `productSales2025` when `projSales()` returns some `Double` value like, lets say `1.0`?

Comment: The result should be 5 numbers from the equation in the method projSales(). These 5 numbers need to be inputted into the equation by the user to estimate the projectedSales for a product.

Comment: Since your `projSales()` only `return projectedSales;` and projectedSales is declared as `double projectedSales` then your method will always return single value stored in `projectedSales`. Method can return only one *thing*, but that thing can hold many other values like an array, so if you want your method to return array why not create such array inside, fill it with data and then return it?

Comment: This shows why static type safety is important and you should have your method `projSales` declared to return the type it actually returns (`double`) rather than the catch-all type `Object`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt @Pshemo thanks for your help. I changed my return type to double and skipped making an array to store the `projectedSales` outcome.